# Novel featuring an AI that backed itself up by encoding data as tattoos

Tags: story-identification, novel, artificial-intelligence

As noted, there was an AI that backed itself up by encoding data in ornate tattoos that were offered free of charge to human clients.  Also it seems to me that the protagonist's favourite expressions were "Stone the crows at home!" and/or "Stone home righteous!" (but I could be conflating multiple novels).

Comment: How did the tattoos work? Did it have to read them each time or were they Wi-Fi type linked? Why tattoos over other forms of storage? How did this play into the story? Who was the protagonist? The AI? Can you remember any plot elements? When did you read this? Was it new at the time? Was it standalone or part of a series? Was the AI good or evil? If you remember anything else you can [edit] your post to include those details.

Comment: In Banks' *Surface Detail* one of the main characters had a customizable "tattoo" that was actually a full-spec combat drone spread out over her body...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this might be [Synners](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/304806.Synners) by Pat Cadigan.

[image: Synners]

The AI is *Art Fish* (short for *Artie Fish* - say it out loud if you haven't got the pun yet). It gets infected by a virus and is restored from data encoded into tattoos by a tattoo artist called *Gator*.

The two phrases you recall are used several times in the book:

> She dug the chip-player out of her bag and popped on the 'phones. It was some stone-home righteous new speed-thrash Keely had zapped to her, and the translation program she had used on it had left it intact.

> Although one time he'd gone to one set up in the middle of some closed-off lanes on the fucking freeway, and there had been something like stone-home righteous retribution to that one

> One of the Beater's old tunes had been stuck in his head with the pictures running, and that had been some stone-home righteous video

and:

> "I guess not." Sam shook her head. "You know this is probably all that'll come of it. Intergalactic subway system. Stone the fucking crows at home. How stupid do they think people are?"

> "Stone the fucking crows at home!" he shouted. "This stuff s infectedl"

and so on.

Comment: Brilliant!  Yes, that's it.  Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: "Stone the crows" is such an Australian saying I'm surprised to discover the author is American.

Comment: It is? Was used in my home, growing up...